# Teensy 2.0 / Atmega32u4 as Keyboard: Send and Receive

Tags: keyboard, arduino, hid, atmega, teensy

I'm currently working on a device which is able to work as a keyboard and communicate via Serial with a self-written software.
Now I have to install serial drivers (from Arduino) on different computers if I want to communicate with my application which I actually want to avoid.

Is there any other solution to solve this problem? Is it possible that my microcontroller works as a keyboard AND is able to send and receive data as HID device?

Thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I actually do something similar with a 32u4, but it receives its serial over the built-in UART. I do this because it's linking between two separate systems. If it were only one system I could implement a 2nd interface. (Don't forget, a USB HID device must have an IN endpoint even if you are not using it.) Or you could just throw a $2 USB/TTL converter on and do it the same as I did.